# Downgrade 'local' packages in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, aptitude, deb, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I recently unticked the "pre-released updates" option in Software Sources on my Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.1 installation. The Ubuntu wiki states the following regarding this source:

> The proposed updates are updates which are waiting to be moved into the recommended updates queue after some testing. They may never reach recommended or they may be replaced with a more recent update.

Roughly 20 installed packages have indeed not made it into recommended updates, and occasionally cause conflicts when I install new software, as related packages of the newer version are unavailable now that I've disabled the source.

**How can I force a downgrade of all packages for which an earlier version exists in a enabled repository?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tool to do this, available [here](http://code.google.com/p/apt-downgrade/).

Comment: Look directly to the issues. It describes the fix, so you can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
sudo apt-get install <package1>=<version1> <package2>=<version2> ...
```

where version matches the latest in recommended updates.

Comment: Yes but how can I generate the required versions programmatically?

Comment: If its only 20 packages, you would've manually typed them by now. ´apt-cache policy <pkg>´ gets you available versions.

Answer (score 0):

This question gives downgrade instructions: [Downgrading linux](https://superuser.com/questions/216711/downgrading-linux)

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you want.  All you can do is "downgrade" to the release that you are using, which undoes any packages that are ahead in the version.