# Downgrading linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-10.10, downgrade

Is there any way to downgrade 10.10 to 10.04 without reinstalling linux ?

Comment: I mean doing this with packages too. Not just kernel

Answer (score 4):

(Copied from [Downgrade from one version to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3659/1059) at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/))

It's **possible** at the level of the packaging tools (apt). But **the resulting system may not be equivalent to doing a reinstall, and you may get errors along the way**. This is because many packages contain specific support for upgrades (e.g. handling changes in configuration files) but not for downgrades.

Normally, apt prefers to install the most recent version of a package. But you can change this through pinning: you can declare that packages from the old release have higher priority than the installed packages, so that they will be downgrades when you do `aptitude dist-upgrade`.

Change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include only the old release (either edit the file or use your favorite GUI), and run `aptitude update`. Then edit `/etc/apt/preferences` (documented in the [`apt_preferences` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)) and add the following lines (to downgrade to lucid):

```
Package: *
Pin: release v=10.04
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Then run `aptitude dist-upgrade`. Every package has a priority greater than 1000, so every package that is present in 10.04 and installed on your system will be downgraded. You'll have to remove packages that weren't in 10.04 manually; they'll be listed under “Obsolete and locally created packages” in aptitude.

Answer (score 2):

There is  [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto)... written for elder versions.